# Use Joysticks in C# to control objects

Tags: c#, joystick

Right now Im using the WASD keys to control an object. Now I want to use joysticks to do the same. Can anyone show me how to adapt my code to do this? All I want to do is replace the if (Input.getKey)spaces with a an if (Input) space that will use the joysticks to move the boat left and right.

```
void drive()
{
    //decrease speed
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
    {
        //in Drive
        if (acceleration > 0 && 
            bucketMode == false)
        {
            acceleration-= 250;
        }
        //in Reverse
        else if (acceleration < 0 &&
            bucketMode == true)
        {
            acceleration += 250;
        }
    }

   //Increases Speed 
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
    {
        //in Drive
        if (acceleration < maxSpeed &&
            bucketMode == false)
        {
            acceleration+= 250;
        }
        //in Reverse
        else if (acceleration > minSpeed &&
            bucketMode == true)
        {
            acceleration -= 250;
        }
    }

    //stops the boat and toggles Bucket mode
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        acceleration = 0;
        if (bucketMode == false)
        {
            //goes into revers
            bucketMode = true;
            craft.bucket(1); //sends bucket as true
        }
        else
        {
            //goes into drive
            bucketMode = false;
            craft.bucket(0);  //sends bucket as false
        }
    }
    //moves forward if speed is +
    if (acceleration < 0)
    {
        //moves backwards at half the speed than in drive, in a smooth motion, speed depending on user input(acceleration)
        this.transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.smoothDeltaTime * ((-acceleration / 500) +1));

        //updates craft speed being displayed
        craft.ChangeSpeed((acceleration/500) * 1.94);
    }
    //moves backward if speed is -
    else if (acceleration > 0)
    {
        //moves forward in a smoothb motion, speed depending on user input(acceleration)
        this.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.smoothDeltaTime * ((acceleration / 250) + 1));

        //updates craft speed being displayed
        craft.ChangeSpeed((acceleration/250) * 1.94);
    }
    //stands still if speed is 0
    else
    {           
    }

    //turns right
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        //turns the boat to the left smoothly, as speed increases, so does turn angle
        this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * Time.smoothDeltaTime * 25 /* ((2 * acceleration / 250) +1)*/);

        //updates boat information(heading and speed)
        craft.ChangeHeading(1 * Time.smoothDeltaTime * 25 /* ((2 * acceleration / 250) +1)*/);
        craft.ChangeSpeed((acceleration/250) * 1.94);

        //if boat is not moving forwards, moves forward slowly, so boat doesn't turn in place
        if (acceleration == 0)
        {
            this.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.smoothDeltaTime / 2);
        }
    }
    //turns left
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        //turns the boat to the right smoothly, as speed increases, so does turn angle
        this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * Time.smoothDeltaTime * 25 /* ((2 * acceleration / 250) +1)*/);

        //updates boat information(heading and speed)
        craft.ChangeHeading(-1 * Time.smoothDeltaTime * 25 /* ((2 * acceleration / 250) +1)*/);
        craft.ChangeSpeed((acceleration/250) * 1.94);

        //if boat is not moving forwards, moves forward slowly, so boat doesn't turn in place
        if (acceleration == 0)
        {
            this.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.smoothDeltaTime / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The most important parts of the code are the if statements for A and D, everything else I just included so you could see how the boat moves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have got multiple options here to go with

1. Use [SlimDx](http://slimdx.org/)
2. [SharpDx](https://code.google.com/p/sharpdx/source/browse/Samples/DirectInput/JoystickApp/Program.cs?r=c2a5b8e19628866fc4e13df4e18aee701d2e48f1)
3. [DirectX](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16704/Interfacing-with-a-Joystick-using-C).

You can use any of these libraries and get the input. Sorry, but it is not as simple as changing if statement.

Comment: OK, so how would one of these look? All the code I ever see for joysticks explains how to instantiate them, but not how to use them for speed or directional control.

Comment: @Flotolk First of all you need to look into these and see which one you want to use, then i have given links as well for you to take a closer look with working examples.